# Formatting a number with a metric prefix (SI style)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I'm looking for an existing solution, for converting a number with a metric prefix (SI style) to float or int.

Additionally, my initial number with a metric prefix is a **string**.

Example:

I have:

```
a = "1u"
b = "2m"
c = "1.1u"
```

I want:

```
a = 0.000001
b = 0.002
c = 0.0000011
```

Comment: just parse it, can you specify the metrics? also, what have you tried already?

Comment: A bit picky - you say prefix but your examples are suffixes! Question: will the string always be a series of numbers with a 1 character indicator at the end? If so, it would be easy to grab the last character and work from there. If not, it would be a regex solution (using (\d+) as a test).

Comment: @DanielSanchez just did some search.

Comment: @Alan ohh sorry, you're right. Regarding your question, unfortunately no. It can be a flat in a string, please have a look on examples, I update them.

Comment: @Alan: They're prefixes.  They come at the end of the string because the units are missing.

Comment: You need to try to code this yourself, I doubt there's a library that will do it for you. If you get stuck, *then* would be the time to post a question here. As Alan states, It's fairly trivial if the last character always specifies the multiplier

Comment: @SiHa I can bet there is a lib or an exiting function for that formatting. If not, I would go for my implementation.

Comment: Well. If you are asking for a library recommendation, then that is off-topic for SO, although I expect Scipy might have something, thinking about it.

Comment: @Paddy, you say "I would go for my implementation" ... can you show your code ?

Comment: the SI multiplier can also be used in the middle, some thing like 1m3 indicating 0.0013 or 6k3 for 6300... although not official, you will find this in many doc's/usages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary of prefices:

```
prefix = {"y":1e-24, "z":1e-21, "a":1e-18, "f":1e-15, "p": 1e-12,
          "n":1e-9, "u":1e-6, "µ":1e-6, "m":1e-3, "c":1e-2, "d":0.1,
          "h":100, "k":1000, "M":1e6, "G":1e9, "T":1e12, "P":1e15,
          "E":1e18, "Z":1e21, "Y":1e24}

def meter(s):
    try:
        # multiply with meter-prefix value
        return float(s[:-1])*prefix[s[-1]]
    except KeyError:
        # no or unknown meter-prefix
        return float(s)


for a in ["1u", "2m", "1.1u", "42", "6k"]:
    print(meter(a))
```

Result:

```
1e-06
0.002
1.1e-06
42.0
6000.0
```

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo 6k3 indicates 6300, not 6003. The multiplier simply replaces the decimal point, so 6k3 = 6.3k

Comment: this does not work if he SI multiplier is used in the middle. Example 6k3 indicating 6300, otherwise this code does work

Comment: Very helpful, thank you for working this out! Out of curiosity, do you already have a way to do the opposite, ie. convert a number to a string with the appropriate prefix?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [QuantiPhy](https://quantiphy.readthedocs.io/en/stable) package. It is a stable well documented and well supported package that is designed to do just what you want.

```
>>> from quantiphy import Quantity

>>> all = dict(
...     a = Quantity('1u'),
...     b = Quantity('2m'),
...     c = Quantity('1.1u)'
... )
>>> for n, v in all.items():
...     print(f'{n} = {v:<0.7f}')
a = 0.000001
b = 0.002
c = 0.0000011
```

Quantity subclasses float, so a quantity can be used anywhere a float can be used.

```
>>> print(sum(all.values()))
0.0020021
```

When printing it you can retain the SI scale factors. You can also add units to make the quantity more descriptive.

```
>>> all = dict(
...     a = Quantity('1ug'),
...     b = Quantity('2mg'),
...     c = Quantity('1.1ug)'
... )
>>> for n, v in all.items():
...     print(f'{n} = {v}')
a = 1 ug
b = 2 mg
c = 1.1 ug
```

It provides many more features as well.

Comment: hmm, didn't know about this package. I was using sympy.physics and want to move to using Pint. In fact, it turns out there are many more packages kdavies4.github.io/natu/seealso.html. I prefer Pint because it allows for integration with both numpy and the uncertainties package, the latter of which offers automated error propagation, and I don't think any of the other packages are compatible with it